# Is there anyway we can call an excel addin using python?

Tags: python, excel, add-in

Is there anyway we can call an excel addin using python?
I would like to call a user-defined add-in which is present in excel using a python program. I need a freeware I think pyxll requires license.

Comment: Have you already tried http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf and if so, where did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can try xlwings if you like to use python inside your excel.

Or try to dispatch excel with win32com

```
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch ("Excel.Application")
```

I think that you'd have to save your add-in as vba project ([How to Use Your Excel Add-In Functions in VBA](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm). 
Generally nearly everything that can be done via VBA could be done with python and dispatched excel, so [VBA Object Model reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is a good documentation on it.